# How Stable Should CPU Frequency Be for Benchmarking?

Tags: linux, cpu, benchmarking, microbenchmark

Note: exhaustive system details are given at the end of the question.

I am trying to get my development machine to have a very stable CPU frequency so that I can get precise benchmarks of some linear algebra codes - however, it still displays significant frequency fluctuations.

I have set scaling governor to `performance` mode:

```
echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

I have also locked everything in the `C0` state:

```
sudo cpupower idle-set -D 0
```

However, using `i7z`, I still observe CPU frequency fluctuations >5%. I would very much appreciate guidance regarding whether there are further steps I should take to constrain the CPU frequency to a fixed value, or whether it is not possible to obtain a more precise frequency constraint.

Appendix:

My processor is an Intel Core i7-9750H:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' 
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
...
```

It has 12 logical CPUs and 6 physical cores:

```
lscpu -a -e
CPU NODE SOCKET CORE L1d:L1i:L2:L3 ONLINE MAXMHZ    MINMHZ
0   0    0      0    0:0:0:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
1   0    0      1    1:1:1:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
2   0    0      2    2:2:2:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
3   0    0      3    3:3:3:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
4   0    0      4    4:4:4:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
5   0    0      5    5:5:5:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
6   0    0      0    0:0:0:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
7   0    0      1    1:1:1:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
8   0    0      2    2:2:2:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
9   0    0      3    3:3:3:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
10  0    0      4    4:4:4:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
11  0    0      5    5:5:5:0       yes    4500.0000 800.0000
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.04:

```
~ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Comment: When you say frequency fluctations, do you mean going down from max frequency in this case? Have you checked that this is not a result of thermal throttling for safety?

Comment: Step back a bit.  What precisely are you trying to time and why.  Are your assumptions correct?

Comment: @Matt first, I'm trying to reproduce some of Agner Fog's instruction latencies using bits of assembler code, then going to use this data to tune some linear algebra code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One case not mentioned in your post is Intel's turbo boost. You can disable it by writing `1` to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`. This setting is also available in BIOS, but I'm not sure if the effects are 100% equivalent.

Comment: this worked - the frequency reported by i7z is now stable to within 1MHz. It looks like disabling turbo is a recommended benchmarking tip, good to know: https://llvm.org/docs/Benchmarking.html